# Combinatorics - rotating people through different groups / tables

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out a rotation schedule for 46 people. We have 6 tables. 5 tables have 4 groups of 2. 1 table has 3 groups of 2.  We have 6 rounds and people are in groups of 2 for each round. The first round, 1 person in each pair presents their sales pitch and the other person listens. For the second round, they rotate to new tables in new groups and have new partners. The rep that presented is now a listener and the listener becomes a presenter. This goes on for all 6 rounds which means a person presents 3 times and listens 3 times, each time at a new table with a new partner.
Table 1 - 4 groups of 2
Table 2 - 4 groups of 2
Table 3 - 4 groups of 2
Table 4 - 4 groups of 2
Table 5 - 4 groups of 2
Table 6 - 3 groups of 2

I cannot, for the life of me,figure out how to do these rotations.

Comment: If you want it exactly as you have said, then it is impossible.  Reason (if I have understood the problem correctly): you have 46 people and they all have to be at every table once, in 6 rounds.  But table 6 only holds 6 people, so in 6 rounds it will only get a maximum of 36 different people, so at least 10 people must miss out on table 6.  So it seems that you will need to relax your requirements.

Comment: So I either have to bump it to 48 tables or someone will sit at a table 2x

Comment: Even if I bump it to 48 tables or people have to sit at the same table twice, I would still need to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Well, if you change the conditions then it **might** be possible.  But maybe it will still be impossible for different reasons.  Sometimes this sort of scheduling task is impossible for very subtle and complicated reasons.  It could be (emphasize: "could be" - I honestly don't have much of a clue) that you would have to make some pretty major changes.

Comment: David, it is not possible since there are 8 people at a table and only 6 tables. I haven't had to work through a problem like this in a while. Thank you for giving me some things to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple trial and error, looks to be correct to me, but someone should look it over again.

Assign a number to each person x=1-46.
After each rotation, new number(y) = mod(3x+8,46)+1.

Thus for Round 1.

Table 1: 1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8
Table 2: 9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
Table 3: 17 18  19  20  21  22  23  24
Table 4: 25 26  27  28  29  30  31  32
Table 5: 33 34  35  36  37  38  39  40
Table 6: 41 42  43  44  45  46

Round 2

12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33
36  39  42  45  2   5   8   11
14  17  20  23  26  29  32  35
38  41  44  1   4   7   10  13
16  19  22  25  28  31  34  37
40  43  46  3   6   9

Round 3

45  8   17  26  35  44  7   16
25  34  43  6   15  24  33  42
5   14  23  32  41  4   13  22
31  40  3   12  21  30  39  2
11  20  29  38  1   10  19  28
37  46  9   18  27  36

Round 4

6   33  14  41  22  3   30  11
38  19  46  27  8   35  16  43
24  5   32  13  40  21  2   29
10  37  18  45  26  7   34  15
42  23  4   31  12  39  20  1
28  9   36  17  44  25

Round 5

27  16  5   40  29  18  7   42
31  20  9   44  33  22  11  46
35  24  13  2   37  26  15  4
39  28  17  6   41  30  19  8
43  32  21  10  45  34  23  12
1   36  25  14  3   38

Round 6

44  11  24  37  4   17  30  43
10  23  36  3   16  29  42  9
22  35  2   15  28  41  8   21
34  1   14  27  40  7   20  33
46  13  26  39  6   19  32  45
12  25  38  5   18  31

Comment: If I am following this correctly, person #1 ends up at table 4 twice and table 5 twice.